# Update specific record based on specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am using SQL Server.

I am having a database table that contains some user data as given below :

```
      ID       UNIT      VAL1  VAL2   MAT1    MAT2    LVL_CODE
BB123456789   FALSE       1     1      ROL     M       NULL
AA004000000   FALSE      40     1      ROL     PAL      8
AA004000000   FALSE       1    72      ROL     CV
AA004000000   FALSE      20     1      ROL     M        6
```

In this table, there are records that are having the same ID for Eg: AA004000000 having THREE records. whereas ID BB123456789 having only one record.

I want to set **UNIT = TRUE, VAL1 = 1, VAL2 = 1** for records that are satisfying the below conditions:

case 1 : If **VAL1 = VAL2** then update UNIT = TRUE,VAL1=1,VAL2=1. if there are multiple records with the same ID satisfying case 1 or VAL1 != VAL2 then we need to **consider case 2.**

case 2:  If  **MAT1 = MAT2** then update UNIT = TRUE,VAL1=1,VAL2=1. if there are multiple records with same ID satisfying case 2 or MAT1 != MAT2 then  **consider case 3.**

case 3: **Update UNIT = TRUE,VAL1=1,VAL2=1 for a ID with lowest LVL_CODE**.
Since we have multiple records with the same ID we need to update only one record to TRUE
eg: ID: AA004000000 has 3 records in that I need to set UNIT = TRUE for only one record where LVL_CODE is Least. The least LVL_CODE for AA004000000 is 6.

So the desired result should be:

```
      ID      UNIT     VAL1  VAL2     MAT1  MAT2    LVL_CODE
BB123456789   TRUE       1     1      ROL     M       NULL
AA004000000   FALSE      40    1      ROL     PAL      8
AA004000000   FALSE      1     72     ROL     CV
AA004000000   TRUE       1     1      ROL     M        6
```

Can anyone help me how to find out such records and update them?

Comment: . . The first reaction is that you are using unsupported software.  You should really upgrade SQL Server to a supported version.  Second, your question is quite hard to follow because the images are barely readable.  You could probably simplify the presentation to focus only on the columns of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in stored procedure, with some changes of course

```
if (select COUNT * from [yourTable] where val1=val2) =1 
begin
     declare @id =scope_identity();
     update [yourTable] set -- -- your values unite true and val1=val2=1
end
else if(select COUNT * from [yourTable] where val1=val2) >1 or exists (select COUNT * from 
[yourTable] where val1!=val2)
begin
if (select COUNT * from [yourTable] where mat1=mat2) =1 
begin
declare @id =scope_identity();
update [yourTable] set -- your values unite true and val1=val2=1

end
else 
if(select COUNT * from [yourTable] where mat1=mat2) >1 or exists (select COUNT * from 
[yourTable] where mat1!=mat2)
begin
declare @id =scope_identity();
update [yourTable] set -- your values unite true and val1=val2=1
end

end
```